# R: create diagonal from 1 to 10 in matrix -> returns only last value

Tags: r, matrix, caching, nested-loops, diagonal

I need to modify a matrix filled with random numbers so that the resulting matrix has a diagonal with the numbers 1 to 10 and everywhere else there are supposed to be zeros.
I am almost done but the diagonal only shows the last value 10 instead of the numbers 1 to 10. I know I need to cache the result somehow but I don't know how to do that.

```
rand_mat = matrix(sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
#10x10 matrix filled with random numbers


for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) {
  #for each row
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) {
    #for each column
    for (o in 1:10){
      #go through numbers 1 to 10 for the diagonal
      
      if(i == j){
        #if row matches column -> diagonal
      
      rand_mat[i,j] = o
      #assign numbers 1 to 10 in the diagonal
      

      }else{
        
        rand_mat[i,j] = 0
        #if location is not in the diagonal assign 0
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

This is the current result:

```
> print(rand_mat)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0   10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0   10    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0   10    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0   10    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0   10    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0   10    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   10    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0   10     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    10
>
```

Comment: Why not just `diag(1:10)`?

Comment: Or if you must start with a random matrix: `rand_mat <- diag(1:10)`.

Comment: I'll try that but we didn't learn about this function yet in our seminar and I think we are only supposed to solve this using functions we learned about during the seminar.

Comment: That only replaces the diagonal. You need to replace the off-diagonal values with 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your innermost loop is unnecessary. When you are looping through `j`, you are looping through each *cell* in row `i`. So you need only assign the value `i` to the cell if `i == j` and `0` otherwise. You don't need the variable `o` at all.

So a fixed-up version of your code might be:

```r
rand_mat = matrix(sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)

for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) {
  #for each row
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) {
    #for each column
      if(i == j) {
        #if row matches column -> diagonal
      
         rand_mat[i,j] <- i
         #assign row number in the diagonal
      } else {
        
        rand_mat[i,j] = 0
        #if location is not in the diagonal assign 0
        
      }
   }
}

rand_mat
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#>  [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [3,]    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [4,]    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0    5    0    0    0    0     0
#>  [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    6    0    0    0     0
#>  [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    7    0    0     0
#>  [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    8    0     0
#>  [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    9     0
#> [10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    10
```

Or, more succinctly:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) 
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) 
      rand_mat[i, j] <- if(i == j) i else 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using only functions you used in your question:

```
rand_mat = matrix(sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
rand_mat <- matrix(0, 10, 10)        # Make all the elements 0.
for(i in 1:10) rand_mat[i, i] <- i   # Replace the diagonal elements
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and the code is definitely a lot shorter :) But do you perhaps know how to do this using the code I wrote? I've had similar problems with loops before that I couldn't cache and only got the last values...

Answer (score 0):

I got it thanks to @dcarlson
Their code was definitely a lot shorter but I really wanted to use my code to see what I was doing wrong. Turns out I had to write `rand_mat[o,o] = o` instead of `rand_mat[i,j] = o` in the if-else-loop. So the code now looks like this:

```
rand_mat = matrix(sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
#10x10 matrix filled with random numbers


for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) {
  #for each row
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) {
    #for each column
    for (o in 1:10){
      #go through numbers 1 to 10 for the diagonal
      
      if(i == j){
        #if row matches column -> diagonal
      
      rand_mat[o,o] = o
      #assign numbers 1 to 10 in the diagonal

      }else{
        
        rand_mat[i,j] = 0
        #if location is not in the diagonal assign 0
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

and the result looks like when I tried it with the code from @dcarlson

```
> print(rand_mat)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    5    0    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    6    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    7    0    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    8    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    9     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    10
>
```

But as I learnt from @Allan Cameron you don't need the variable `o` so you don't even need the third for-loop:

```
rand_mat = matrix(sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)

for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) {
  #for each row
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) {
    #for each column
    if(i == j) {
      #if row matches column -> diagonal
      
      rand_mat[i,j] <- i
      #assign row number in the diagonal
      
    } else {
      
      rand_mat[i,j] = 0
      #if location is not in the diagonal assign 0
      
    }
  }
}
```

The result is the same. Thank you for your help!

Comment: you don't need `o` at all, since you can just use `i` or `j` here.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it without ```o``` and it works the same but I don't entirely understand how it works... How does it know that I just want the numbers from 1 to 10? Because I only have 10 rows/columns?

Comment: think about the very first loop. `i` is 1. Then, we go into the `j` loop. In the first iteration, `j` is 1. So when we come to test `i == j`, the answer is TRUE. So we write the value of `i` (which is 1) into `rand_mat[i, j]`. But this is `rand_mat[1, 1]` since both `i` and `j` are 1 at this point. Then we move on to `j` being 2, but `i` is still 1, so `i == j` is FALSE and we write a zero into `rand_mat[1, 2]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an efficent way to do this (as noted in comments), you can fix your code by removing the innermost loop and replacing it with an assignment:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(rand_mat)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(rand_mat)) {
    rand_mat[i,j] = if(i == j) i else 0 
      }
    }
```